# jQuery change decimal into an integer and check if it's bigger or smaller than another integer

Tags: jquery

I have a shopping cart with a minimum of $75 and I need to check if the subtotal is smaller than 75 or not. The issue I'm having with is trying to get the decimal (Ex: $150.87) to be just an integer, and only grab everything before the decimal. So if the subtotal is "$150.87" I only want "150." I'm able to remove the $ as you can see in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/51q4cd70/ but I'm not sure how to remove everything after the decimal. I can't just replace ".87" because the subtotal is going to be different every time. I tried using regex but it's really complicated for me.

My coding is below:

```
if ($('#LogonImageLink').val() == "LogOff") {
    //YOU ARE LOGGED OFF
    var subtotal = $('.ShoppingCart_SubTotalText').text().replace("$", "");

    if ($(subtotal) < 75) {
        alert('this number is bigger');
    }

    else {
        alert('this number is smaller');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
If ((parseInt (subtotal))>75){}

Comment: I test it in your example and it works, you should delete the '$' before (subtotal). Do you nees the result Int or float ?